# Target Silverlight Version is stuck

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have my shiny new Visual Studio 2010.  I want to develop a Silverlight 4 web app with it.

I made a project and it told me that I needed to update my Developer version of Silverlight.  I followed the link provided and did what it suggested.

I then went back and created my project (under a different directory).

But when I try to select the target version of Silverlight all I can see is Silverlight 3.

What do I need to do to get this to show the Silverlight 4 option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you've installed the [Silverlight 4 Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=40ef0f31-cb95-426d-9ce0-00dcfabf3df5&displaylang=en) to enable this all in VS 2010.