# VS2010 Target Silverlight Version 2.0?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-2.0

I've just upgraded to VS2010 as I was running into problems with a Silverlight project that I needed to be built in 2.0 but I also needed other projects built in 3.0.

I read about VS2010's ability to specify the Silverlight Target version and figured it was time to upgrade to solve my problem.

I've installed 2010 and have also installed the Silverlight 2 SDK, but when I open my Silverlight project, the only option available under Target Silverlight Version is Silverlight 3.

After googling for a bit, I found another Stack Overflow post that seemed to present a solution:

[Target Silverlight Version is stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260453/target-silverlight-version-is-stuck)

However, the particular solution is for adding Silverlight 4 to the dropdown; there doesn't seem to be a Silverlight 2 Tools for VS2010, and the Silverlight 2 Tools for VS2008 won't install because I haven't got VS2008 installed.

Can anyone shed any light on a possible solution for me?

Cheers,
Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight 2 development is not supported in VS2010.  You need to use VS2008 for that.  Luckily, 2008 and 2010 can be installed side-by-side with no problems.

Comment: Balls. Multi-targeting is the only reason I upgraded.

Comment: I think they were originally going to support v2, but they only went with v3 and v4 in the end.